# Contextual Filter with Title and Language

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I'm building an api that is going to change base on the title and the language that is been request. This request is base on the URL something like this www.example.com/abc/fr-fr

- **abc** = title of the content
- **fr-fr** = Language Code name

For some reason the context filter of the language is turning my search into empty. Here is what happen when I try to run **www.example.com/abc/fr-fr**

```
{
  "nodes" : []
}
```

And it should looks like this instead:

```
{
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "node" : {
        "Literal Api" : "{\n \"glossary\": {\n \"title\": \"example glossary\",\n\t\t\"GlossDiv\": {\n \"title\": \"S\",\n\t\t\t\"GlossList\": {\n \"GlossEntry\": {\n \"ID\": \"SGML\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"SortAs\": \"SGML\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"GlossTerm\": \"Standard Generalized Markup Language\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Acronym\": \"SGML\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"Abbrev\": \"ISO 8879:1986\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"GlossDef\": {\n \"para\": \"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"GlossSeeAlso\": [\"GML\", \"XML\"]\n },\n\t\t\t\t\t\"GlossSee\": \"markup\"\n }\n }\n }\n }\n}",
        "Title" : "abc",
        "Language" : "French"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Things that I have already try it out:

1. I thought that the problem was having multiple contextual filters
   but that did not fix the problem because I try using it only the
   language contextual filter and I still have the same problem.
2. Also, I try to use the word "**French**" instead of the language
   code, which is **"fr-fr"** and this did not fix the problem.

Here is my view configuration: 
[image: View Configuration]

**Note** I'm using node translation in 7, not entity/field translation. Each language has its own copy of a node.

My question is why I'm getting an empty node instead of the entire node information?

Comment: **I believe you can only use 1 contextual filter** using 2 or more will give you blanks.

Comment: @NoSssweat any reference for this claim? As far as I remember, it's simply not true.

Comment: @Molot no reference, speaking from experience. Every time I've tried using 2, the view breaks.

Comment: @NoSssweat either your version has a bug, you are unlucky, or you are doing something wrong. In order of probability.

Comment: Long time ago, multiple contextual filter was not supported it. However, the latest version of views I know support multiple contextual filter because I have done it on other places.

See my first bullet points on things that I have try it out.
`I thought that the problem was having multiple contextual filters but that did not fix the problem because I try using it only the language contextual filter and I still have the same problem.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple contextual filters are fine & dandy. 
The issue seems to be that the url prefix being used in a translated/localized content is a bit different from the actual machine code for the language. French is not 'fr-fr' but simply 'fr' in Drupal's views. French Canadian would be 'fr-ca'.

here is a list of defined languages I use on my site along with their codes. These should be what you're looking to filter on. No issues with multiple filters.

[image]

Comment: I was using the wrong language code. This seem to solve my problem thank you.